# Proving $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ has 4 roots

Tags: polynomials

Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be a prime number.
I want to show that if the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ has one root then he has three other roots.

My attempt was the following:

If $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, so $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ must be divided by $x-a$. I checked and $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x-a)[x^3+(a+1)x^2+(a^2+a+1)x+(a^3+a^2+a+1)]$$
(when assuming that indeed $a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1=0$).
I thought I can show that $x^3+(a+1)x^2+(a^2+a+1)x+(a^3+a^2+a+1)$ has three roots other then $a$, but I didn't find a way.

Comment: This is false if $p=5$ unless you count multiplicities because $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x-1)^4 \bmod 5$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A root $\zeta$ of this polynomial is nothing else but an element of order $5$ in $(\mathbb Z_p)^*$. If such an element exists, of course there exist four of them ($\zeta, \zeta^2, \zeta^3, \zeta^4$).

---

One should mention that this proof works for any integral domain (You might have to count multiplicities of course). It even works for any commutative ring with unit, but if there are zero-divisors, we might even have more roots than four.